# Unit test annotation based Spring MVC Portlet controller

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit, spring-annotations

I am a newbie learning spring mvc with portlets. I have a controller which returns the view. I am not sure how to write the unit test that controller.

```
@controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class HelloController {

@ResourceMapping(value = "hello")
public String helloWorld(RenderRequest request) {

    return "hello";
}
```

and my Unit Test controller is something like this

```
public class HelloWorldControllerTest extends TestCase {

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
}

protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}

public void testHelloWorldController() throws IOException {

          MockRenderRequest request = new MockRenderRequest();
        HelloController c = new HelloController ();
        ModelAndView result = c.helloWorld(request);
        assertNotNull("ModelAndView should not be null", result);
        assertEquals("hello", result.getViewName());
}
```

This is not working as the **result** is not a ModelAndView object but it is a String in the controller. The return type can be a ModelAndView object in the main controller but if using spring annotation based then from the examples I have found the return type is String. Can anyone suggest which is the best practice or if I am wrong in understanding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [spring-test-mvc](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc) project facilitates testing Spring MVC controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout spring-test-portlet-mvc (https://github.com/markusf/spring-test-portlet-mvc) to integration test your Spring controllers.